How to exclude certain classes form code coverage calculations using jacoco?
I am trying to instrument code coverage for my Quarkus application.
When running mvn clean install everything works fine and code coverage is shown as expected and the classes are excluded.
But when running mvn test the classes which are supposed to be excluded form coverage calculations are not!
what would be the error ?
I tried with this configuration but it is not working!
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Prepare agent -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <exclClassLoaders>*QuarkusClassLoader</exclClassLoaders>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/quarkus/configurations/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</destFile>
                            <append>true</append>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/quarkus/configurations/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</dataFile>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-report</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-quarkus.exec</dataFile>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/quarkus/configurations/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>



You can use the quarkus,jacoco.excludes configuration property.
